# jQuery - Show and Hide when element is 190px from the bottom of screen?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, web

So I need an offsetBottom() jQuery function essentially. I have a fixed div that overlays the entire website, but I also have a div at the bottom of each page which contains the exact same content. My goal is to get the fixed overlay to disappear once the TOP of the div at the bottom of the page becomes visible, or is at the same height from the bottom as the overlay, even when the page is resized, then the overlay re-appears when the top of the div goes below the fixed div.

I am sorry I have no code example, I have been trying to use offsetTop() but the pages are of varying heights and it will only show/hide when the div reaches the very top of the web browser.

Comment: would something like this not work? `$(window).height() - elementYPosition < 190` and attach that to the scroll event

Comment: is this what you're going for? https://codepen.io/mcoker/pen/owmOqK

Comment: I think that may work Michael, I will give it a shot... if you want to answer below, I will star your answer if it does